# API testing in C# - how do I compare entire JSON response in 1 assertion?

Tags: c#, api, testing

I am writing API tests with VS & C#

I have a test that looks like this:

```
[TestCase("buddy")]
public void CreatePet(string name)
{
    //Setup Request
    RestRequest = new RestRequest("pet", Method.POST);

    //Load JSON File
    string RequestBody = Utils.LoadJson("CreatePet.json");
    RestRequest.AddParameter("application/json", RequestBody, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    //Call REST Resource
    ResponseJSON = JSON_NET_GetResponse(RestRequest);

    //Verify Response JSON
    ((string) ResponseJSON.name).Should().Be("doggie");
    ((string) ResponseJSON.status).Should().Be("available");
    ((Int64) ResponseJSON.id).Should().BeGreaterThan(Int32.MaxValue);
    ((string) ResponseJSON.tags[0].name).Should().Be("string");
    ((int) ResponseJSON.tags.Count).Should().Be(1);    
}
```

Notice I have 5 asserts there.  I am asserting on most of the lines of the returned JSon.

Is it possible to simply write 1 assert that ensures the entire Json is the same as it was last time?  I assume I'd need to ignore certain things like GUIDs and timestamps... but otherwise I don't want to be line by line writing asserts for every single thing... in some cases my Json responses could be 50 lines long...

I'm assuming this is a solved problem and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.  How do you guys do it?

The Json response for my test looks like this:

```
{
  "id": 379856466726,
  "category": {
    "id": 0,
    "name": "string"
  },
  "name": "doggie",
  "photoUrls": [
    "string"
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "string"
    }
  ],
  "status": "available"
}
```

Comment: If you know what to expect in the response then why not compare the json strings for equality

Comment: I also need it to ignore things like dynamic timestamps and GUIDs.  I'm wondering if there is already a solution for this.

Comment: But you originally said that u wanted to compare the entire JSON response. There is not enough information in your post to provide meaningful assistance. please provide a [mcve]

Comment: But I did say that I wanted to ignore stuff in my original post... I said:  "Is it possible to simply write 1 assert that ensures the entire Json is the same as it was last time? I assume I'd need to ignore certain things like GUIDs and timestamps... but otherwise I don't want to be line by line writing asserts for every single thing... "

Comment: Ok I understand now. You're probably going to have to continue asserting line by line or if there is some way to isolate the portion of json you want to assert

Answer (score 0):

I found this github project which looks like the kind of thing I wanted here:

https://github.com/chancancode/json_expressions